# Drop unmatched values in a aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate, aggregation

have a collection like this

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("5ab9cbe531c2ab715d42129a"),
    p_id: ObjectId("507f191e810c19729de860ea"),
    name: "elmaro",
    mobile: 112466,
    area: "texas",
    mapped: [
      {
        _id: ObjectId("5e13642ee88247a6b4f2c0f9"),
        p_id: ObjectId("507f191e810c19729de860eb"),
        effected: "12",
        tested: "14255",
        negative: "1658451"
      },
      {
        _id: ObjectId("5e13642ee88247a6b4f2c0f1"),
        p_id: ObjectId("507f191e810c19729de860ea"),
        effected: "254",
        tested: "54851",
        negative: "158521541"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("5ab9cbe531c2ab715d52128a"),
    p_id: ObjectId("507f191e810c19729de860ea"),
    name: "hukke",
    mobile: 112466,
    area: "texas",
    mapped: [
      {
        _id: ObjectId("5e13642ee88247a6b4f2c0f9"),
        p_id: ObjectId("507f191e810c19729de860ea"),
        effected: "1222",
        tested: "3545621",
        negative: "354168512"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

It has to be mapped with `p_id`. and the unmatched array should be dropped like this.

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("5ab9cbe531c2ab715d42129a"),
    p_id: ObjectId("507f191e810c19729de860ea"),
    name: "elmaro",
    mobile: 112466,
    area: "texas",
    mapped: [
      {
        _id: ObjectId("5e13642ee88247a6b4f2c0f1"),
        p_id: ObjectId("507f191e810c19729de860ea"),
        effected: "254",
        tested: "54851",
        negative: "158521541"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("5ab9cbe531c2ab715d52128a"),
    p_id: ObjectId("507f191e810c19729de860ea"),
    name: "hukke",
    mobile: 112466,
    area: "texas",
    mapped: [
      {
        _id: ObjectId("5e13642ee88247a6b4f2c0f9"),
        p_id: ObjectId("507f191e810c19729de860ea"),
        effected: "1222",
        tested: "3545621",
        negative: "354168512"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Mongo version : 4.0.14

Answer (score 1):

Use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) to replace existing collection and [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to remove non-matching sub-documents:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            mapped: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$mapped",
                    cond: {
                        $eq: [ "$$this.p_id", "$p_id" ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/icHDEqOw6Lc)